# Which function allows me to specify by date AND time?

Tags: function, date, time, google-sheets

The documentation for the DATEVALUE function (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en) states that you can use `=DATEVALUE("7/11/14 9:00 PM")` to return not just the date but the time as well, but for the life of me no matter what I do, time always says `00:00:00` or `12:00 AM` depending on the display format I choose..

In one of my `IF` functions, I need to specify an exact date and time.  Nothing, however, seems to  give me back the specific date and time together.

When testing the various date and time functions, I get the following:

`DATEVALUE("7/11/14 9:00 PM")` returns `7/11/14 12:00 AM` (shows 12:00 AM no matter what time I put).

`TIMEVALUE("7/11/14 9:00 PM")` returns `12/30/1899 9:00PM` (shows 12/30/1899 no matter what date I put).

The DATE function doesn't work because the input  is limited to DATE(year, month, day)

The TIME function doesn't work because the input is limited to TIME(hour, minute, second)

There doesn't seem to be a function that allows for both date and time.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with ifs in cascade, the first if will check the date while the second checks the time, like this:

```
=if(datevalue(A1) = datevalue("7/11/14 9:00 PM"), if(timevalue(A1) = timevalue("7/11/14 9:00 PM"), "TRUE", "FALSE"), "FALSE")
```